# Form working locally, and not in heroku? Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku

My form seems to work perfectly fine locally, but gives me a syntax error on heroku. Here is my code thats causing the error:

```
<%= form_for (@item, {:url => [@company, @item]}) do |item_form| %>
```

The error is:

syntax error, unexpected '}', expecting keyword_end
2011-09-24T22:25:25+00:00 app[web.1]: ...e, {:url => [@company, @item]}) do |item_form| @output_buf...

Then when I tried

```
<%= form_for (@item, :url => [@company, @item]) do |item_form| %>
```

It gave me this error:

syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting ')'
2011-09-24T22:18:01+00:00 app[web.1]: ...ffer.append=  form_for (@share, :url => [@company, @share])

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should remove the space between the method call `form_for` and the opening parenthesis `(`.  As a general rule, never do this.  It's ambiguous and may result in the parser thinking that you're calling `form_for` with one argument, like this:

```
<%= form_for((@item, :url => [@company, @item])) do |item_form| %>
```

... which would be a syntax error, resulting in the errors you're seeing (e.g. unexpected comma)

```
# it should be:
<%= form_for(@item, :url => [@company, @item]) do |item_form| %>

# or, remove the parentheses altogether (up to your usage tastes):
<%= form_for @item, :url => [@company, @item] do |item_form| %>
```